# Proper way to test for equality in Jest unit test for a PostCSS plugin

Tags: jestjs, postcss

I'm writing a PostCSS plugin to support nested import statements in CSS and I'm running into this issue where my unit test is returning slightly different output than I would expect, resulting in test failures:

```
var postcss = require('postcss');

var plugin = require('./');

function run(input, output, opts) {
  return postcss([ plugin(opts) ]).process(input)
    .then(result => {
      expect(result.css).toEqual(output);
      expect(result.warnings().length).toBe(0);
  });
}


it('replaces @import with the contents of the file being imported.', () => {
  return run('@import "./vendor.css";',
             ".vendor { background: silver; }");
});
```

`./vendor.css` looks like this:

```
.vendor { background: silver; }
```

Results in:

```
FAIL  ./index.test.js
replaces @import with the contents of the file being imported.

expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  ".vendor { background: silver; }"
Received:
  ".vendor {
    background: silver
}"
```

Here's the plugin code: https://github.com/eriklharper/postcss-nested-import/blob/master/index.js#L36-L57

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I can't tell if this is an issue with PostCSS or Jest, or both?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue neither in PostCSS nor Jest!

PostCSS is returning a string with indented CSS while Jest is comparing it with a one-line declaration. The result is 2 different string being compared.

Luckily, you might fix it in endless different ways.

The most trivial is probably to [minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css) both actual and expected results before comparing.

If you'd like something cooler for your project, you might [extend Jest default matcher](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#expectextendmatchers), to be able to compare different formatted CSS strings.